# Any other way to load first view from last view in navigation

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

there are 4 views in my application.

Navigating from first view to second view ... from second  view to third view .... from third view to fourth view...

Now when i select fourth view i need to navigate it to first view.

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

I loaded my first view nib file... its working........

Is there any alternative way ... any another way to navigate from fourth view to first view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will return back to your first view controller.